# SAS HTPMINE Write the ouptut to same file as input

Tags: sas, text-mining, stemming

Using hptmine procedure in SAS, is it possible to write the output to the same file or write to a file in the same format as in the input after Stemming operation is done

Comment: Well according to documentation you can define **outterms = outterms** http://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=tmhpprcref&docsetTarget=tmhpprcref_hptmine_sect051.htm&docsetVersion=14.2&locale=en

Comment: What is your goal exactly - do you want the output file to contain all that is in input file, but with non-stemmed words replaced for their stems?

Comment: @hannafrc exactly

Answer (score 0):

It seems it is not possible. Stemming is the part of parsing phase of `hptmine` procedure. According to [documentation](http://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=tmhpprcref&docsetTarget=tmhpprcref_hptmine_sect008.htm&docsetVersion=14.2&locale=pl#) the only output data set for `parse` statement that contains a full list of terms after stemming operation is done, is `OUTTERMS=` data set.

Instead, to replace terms for their stems in your original file, you can make use of `OUTTERMS=` data set in a sas code that will follow `hptmine` procedure.

For example, create a dictionary:

```
proc sql;
create table work.child_parent as
select child.term as term_child, parent.term as term_parent
from OUTTERMS child
inner join OUTTERMS parent 
on child.parent = parent.key
where child._ispar="." and child.role ne "NOUN_GROUP"
;
quit;
```

and use the dictionary as a lookup table in a code that goes through original text file and replaces each encountered `term_child` for its stem -`term_parent`.